# How are these methods of writing functions different?

Tags: javascript

I have code that has the following functions written:

```
testing: function() {

  ///
}
```

what is the difference of writing it as :

```
testing() {
     ///
}
```

Do they mean the same thing and have the same purpose?

Comment: the first is not valid JS, you meant: `testing = function()...` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes It's valid as part of an object literal.

Comment: yes, i know, but it is not mentioned here

Comment: @CalvinNunes In that case the second isn't valid, either, it should be `function testing() { ... }`

Comment: The two are equivalent if they're part of an object literal.

Comment: now if it were an arrow function there would be some differences